# How to drill down into Sonarqube coverage reports and see changes in coverage and specific files responsible

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube5.6, sonarqube5.3, kpi

We like the ability we have with sonarqube to see in detail the changes in source code that are impacting our KPIs, for example using a project's technical debt tab in version 5.3 we can see in RED the added issues for example, click on these numbers and see the underlying files responsible for the change.

What we are missing is the same exact feature for COVERAGE KPIs, currently we are not given the option to click on a delta in the coverage tab and see files and associated changes, is it something available but we are not seeing ? is this sth coming soon? We also have version 5.6 and I did not find the option in there as well.

Comment: i know this will probably not be helpful, as it is not addressing your problem, but in sonarqube 6.x you have a metric called "Coverage on new Code", we also added this to our quality gate, and it is not allowed to drop below a specific threshhold

Comment: I have access to this KPI in 5.6 and it is allowing me to get the detail per file. This is helpful but works only for the leak period - better than nothing.

Comment: In sonarqube 5.3 the leak period coverage is always empty ("---") does anyone know why? is it not available for that version?

Comment: do you provide the testresults correctly, how does your config look like - if you do not tell sonar to use your coverage data (eg. from jacoco) it can not compute the coverage

Comment: Yea it's working fine : the jacoco test reports are imported as expected. there is just this ("---") in the leak period coverage with absolutely no friendly indication nearby to clarify what is the issue.

Comment: so for this, you should probably provide information like, how did you define leak period - based on time, or on version? and how you generally configured the project :D

Comment: This will be moved to a new question if issue persists since it is a related but separate issue.